# Batch Search Folder for Movies Under 1080p

Tags: video

Would it at all be possible to batch search a folder for movies under 1080p and print out a result of just those movies?

Answer (score 2):

The `mediainfo` program can give video size information

```
sudo apt install mediainfo
```

For 1080p height size must be 1080
Display Video Height with mediainfo

```
mediainfo --Output='Video;%%Height%' /path/to/video-file.mkv
```

Now lets batch and find video files under 1080p

```
#!/bin/bash

# Working Dir SETTINGS, Adapt to your needs
MFolder=~/Video
# script may be modified to be passed as parameter

# Files list: find Video files and output filename
# find $MFolder -type f -exec file -N -i -- {} + | sed -n 's!: video/[^:]*$!!p' | sort

# Will loop an array. Could run a read while
# Save IFS
OLDIFS=$IFS
IFS=$'\n'
# Find all VIDEO files and store names into an array
fileArray=($(find $MFolder -type f -exec file -N -i -- {} + | sed -n 's!: video/[^:]*$!!p' | sort))
# Restore IFS
IFS=$OLDIFS

# Length of array: total num of found videos
NbTotal=${#fileArray[@]}

# Cosmetic
bold=$(tput bold)
normal=$(tput sgr0)

# The loop 
for (( i=0; i<${NbTotal}; i++ ));
do
    VidHeight=$(mediainfo --Output='Video;%Height%' "${fileArray[$i]}")
        if [ "$VidHeight" -lt 1080 ]; then
            ((NbUnder1080++))
            echo "${fileArray[$i]} "${bold}$(mediainfo --Output='Video;%Width% x %Height%' "${fileArray[$i]}")${normal}
        fi
done

# Output report
echo "---"
echo "Folder scanned: $MFolder"
echo "$NbTotal Videos found"
echo "$NbUnder1080 are under 1080p"
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but I'm not sure if there is an easier way than writing a script that individually extracts video resolutions and then screened out the ones you didn't want to see... This is not a complete solution, but might get you going:

```
for i in *.mp4
do
    RESOLUTION=$(ffmpeg -i $i 2>&1 | grep 'Stream.*:Video' | ....)
    if [ $RESOLUTION smaller than 1080p ]
    then
        echo $i

    fi
done
```

The '...' will need some 'sed' or 'awk' to extract the right resolution information - I've a script which does something of this, but is specific to the kinds of files I'm processing, so won't generalise. And then, once you've got resolution data you'll have to come up with a way of comparing it and deciding whether it matches 1080p - is a "good enough" comparison to only look at the X or Y resolution, or do you need to take both X and Y into account.

Comment: what if there are spaces in filenames ?